# How to compute a Many2Many field?

Tags: many-to-many, odoo, odoo-14

I need to get a list containing all the users in a Many2many field, but I can't get the compute method to work.
Here's how my compute method looks by now :

```
def _get_all_employee_id(self):
    for record in self:
        record.employee_id = self.env['res.users'].search([('id', '=', 2)])
```

Here's how my field looks by now :

```
employee_id = fields.Many2many(comodel_name="res.users", string="Employé", compute='_get_all_employee_id', inverse_name='id', store=True)
```

This has no impact at all (wrote "('id', '=', 2)" to test my compute method, but I'd like to remove it, to get every user.).

Comment: Why do you want to store the field?

Comment: And there is no `inverse_name` on Many2many fields.

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like that.

```py
partners = self.env['res.users'].search([])
record.employee_id = (6, 0, partners.ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to overpass my problem yesterday.

Here's the final code :

```
employee_id = fields.Many2many(comodel_name="hr.employee", string="Employé", compute='_get_all_employee_id', store=True)

def _get_all_employee_id(self):
    for record in self:
        record.employee_id = self.env['hr.employee'].search([])
```

The `inverse_name` was the problem, and I think the compute method wasn't triggered some times...

Thank you to the ones who answered my post.